# how do i return an address of a member data by using a function

Tags: c++, sdl

i have my Engine class that contains the SDL_renderer* and I've been trying to get its address by using a function getRenderer but it returns null beside the fact that i have already initialize it (renderer) in the Engine.cpp

```
class Engine
{
    public:
      SDL_Renderer* GetRenderer() { return m_renderer; } // null

      Engine() {}
      ~Engine() {}
private:
    bool m_Running = true;

   SDL_Window* m_window;
   SDL_Renderer* m_renderer;
 };


bool Engine::init()
{
   // initialize SDL
   if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) >= 0)
   {
      // if succeeded create our window
      m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("the title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
          SDL_WIDTH, SDL_HEIGHT, false);

      Engine* engine = new Engine();
      std::cout << engine->GetRenderer() << std::endl;
      if (m_window != nullptr)
      {
          std::cout << "entering this";
          m_renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(m_window, -1, 0);
      }
      else
      {
          return false; // sdl could not initialize
      }
      std::cout << m_renderer<< std::endl; // this is not null
      std::cout << engine->GetRenderer()<<std::endl; // this is null

      textureManager = new TextureManager();
      textureManager->Load("tree", "Assets/tree.png"); // tree for tree texture
      m_Running = true;
      return true;
  }
 }
```

Comment: There is no guarantee what the value of `m_renderer` is, given the code you posted.  You don't have it set to `nullptr` in the `Engine` default constructor, and the `init` function only sets it conditionally.

Comment: `bool Engine::init()` isn't a part of the class definition.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie even though it receives the adddress that SDL_CreateRenderer has returned and in the code i call it using two ways the first just calling it directly and the second one by using the engine pointer the first it returns a value of its address but the second don't this part i don't understand.

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo its already there because if its not i won't be able to compile the program.

Comment: @saad.ben I'm staring at the definition you shared right now. It's not there.

Comment: @saad.ben -- All we have is the code you're showing us.  You did not initialize that pointer in the constructor, thus it has an undefined value.  Second, `init` can return `false`, thus never setting that value.  A description of what you are doing is not enough -- the only thing that is relevant is the code we are seeing.

Comment: Re: `the first just calling it directly and the second one by using the engine pointer` - is that pointer pointing to the same instance of the `Engine`? Please post the calling code.

Comment: Even better: Make a [mcve].

Comment: If it is a different instance of `Engine`, and the return is `nullptr`, then that is not only a logic problem, the issue of not initializing the pointer becomes relevant.  What if you got a garbage value back, believing it was the `m_renderer` value that was set by `SDL_CreateRenderer`?  You're lucky the value was `nullptr`, else your question would have been different -- "why does my code crash when I use `m_renderer`?"

Comment: in the main i called init() by using another pointer of type Engine that don't point to the same instance i guess as mentioned earlier this is the problem but i need a confirmation is it what really causing the problem?

Comment: because in main i did:  Engine* engine = new Engine(); engine->init();

Comment: "_i guess as mentioned earlier this is the problem but i need a confirmation is it what really causing the problem?_" - You obviously want us to guess what your program is really doing instead of making a [mcve]. I won't take part.

Comment: @TedLyngmo that's what i did and it turns out that the i was using different pointers one for getting the addressing and one for calling the whole function, that's why i got the null value but as soon as i used the same pointer i got the address

Comment: @saad.ben No, you did not provide a [mcve] but I'm glad it worked out.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes sorry  i didn't post it,  i thought there will be no need for it because i figured it out, but that technique of doing a minimal code to spot where the problem is, is really helpful thanks for mentioning that i'll be using it next time and thanks to everybody for their precious answers u guys are the best!

Comment: @saad.ben "_that technique of doing a minimal code to spot where the problem is, is really helpful_" - Indeed. I use it very often myself, even to prove it to myself. One of "me" is usually wrong. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you run your C++ app in debug mode, it "clears" (set's to 0) all the uninitialized variables (not necessarily BTW). If you try to compile and run in release mode, you might get a non-zero value from the function. That's why it is always recommended and necessary to initialize your variables in the constructor. Even more, if you have a member raw pointer, you should be very careful, and consider having proper constructors and destructors.

## Edit

In your case, at least, I would suggest to initialize the variables and set them to be `nullptr` in the constructors initializer-list and then call `Init` directly from the constructor.

Maybe, there's a better solution, but this can be considered as a quick fix.

## Edit 2

Worths to be mentioned the comment below: **DONT FORGET ABOUT COPY AND MOVE CONSTRUCTORS**

Comment: *consider having proper constructors and destructors* As well as having support for proper copy and move semantics. [See the Rules of Three Five and Zero for details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: the problem here doesn't have anything to do with m_renderer because what confuse me the most is m_renderer has already a value since it recieves what SDL_CreateRenderer() returns, in the code above i call it using two ways the first just calling it directly and the second one by using the engine pointer the first it returns a value of its address but the second don't this part i don't understand.

Comment: Did you get "entering this" message?

Comment: YES and the  value of its address too (m_renderer) when i tried to print it out but not by using the engine->getRenderer() function

Comment: Do you have the Init function declared in the class body?

Comment: @saad.ben -- How do we know `SDL_Renderer` didn't return `false`?

Comment: yes its already there because if its not i guess i won't be able to compile the program

Comment: @saad.ben Now you are repeating things already questioned. We don't see that it's already there. Make a [mcve].